# ASP MVC Razor if statement with javascript inside

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is what I'm trying to do in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (ViewBag.scroll != null)
    {
        console.log("viewbag data: " + @ViewBag.scroll);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("no viewbag data");
    }
</script>
```

I'd like to execute some jQuery code depending if the `ViewBag` has data, but it is giving me this error:

> the name 'console' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Surround the `console.log` lines with `<text> ... </text>` tags.

Comment: Silly mistake, thank you @Cᴏʀʏ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign it to a variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hasScroll = @ViewBag.scroll != null;
    if (hasScroll) {
        console.log("viewbag data: " + @ViewBag.scroll);
    } else {
        console.log("no viewbag data");
    }
</script>
```